# Full/Lite APP with 2 targets in same codebase

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I developed a game and registered a name as (drifter) now i am planning to release FULL and LITE versions as in lite version user can play the game upto 99points after scoring 99points i added gameover and store button for full version. With the help of  RAYWENDERLICH tutorial  http://www.raywenderlich.com/68613/create-paid-lite-version-iphone-app ( thanks Dani Arnaout for great tutorial) I created lite version target in xcode, now I made 2 targets (drifter and drifterlite )in one codebase.which is the best way to submit the app for review to appstore, do i need to create New App in itunes connect for (DrifterLite)lite version or anyother way.if im proceeding in wrong way please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need two apps in the App Store. Each with its own name and app id (bundle id).

You will have to create two apps in Xcode and submit both for review.

The easier option is to have one app with in-app purchase. Then you just need one target and one app in the app store.

There are pros and cons to both approaches. You need to decide which is best for you and your app.

IAP Pros: One app. Less work.
IAP Cons: No promo codes for IAP. Free apps get more bad reviews because they are free and any idiot can download and review.

2 Apps Pros: Promo codes for full version. Full (paid) versions tend to have better reviews
2 Apps Cons: More work building and deploying two apps.

Comment: thanks for the answer rmaddy so i need to have in-app purchase for lite version ? to get the full app, what are pros and cons approaches?i proceed this way i thought its easy to manage in one codebase

Comment: You have two options: 1) Two apps, one Lite, one Full. or 2) One app. It starts off with limited features and IAP lets the user pay to get the full features.

Comment: i dont have much features in my game its just ads on free one and they can play upto 99 points and in full app ads free and play full game, which one is better way u think

Comment: I updated my answer with some pros and cons of both. It's up to you. But using IAP to remove ads is very common in many games and other apps.

Comment: No. As I clearly stated in my answer and the 1st comment, if you use IAP you only have one version of your app.