# How to submit multiple versions of an app using multiple targets with a single codebase?

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, app-store-connect

*Context:*
I have a single app, with its unique bundle and app id, etc. Basically the most common situation: a single account with a single app. But now, I need to generate N different apps from the same codebase, each to target a specific country; all associated to the same account (I guess).
At first, the idea is to allow custom skins (app icon, app name, launchscreen, localisations, some resources, etc) but eventually features and more core behaviour will probably be customised (this I don't care yet).

*Solution:*
From some SO solutions, as well as ideas like [this github project](https://github.com/brennanMKE/MultipleTargets) or [this ray wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/68613/create-paid-lite-version-iphone-app), I decided to work with multiple targets, each defining a custom configuration and resources to be used.

***The Problem:***
**How on Earth do I manage to release the N different versions of the app?**
From what I understand according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091173/full-lite-app-with-2-targets-in-same-codebase), I'll end up with several App Ids within the same account, each with its Certificates and Provisioning Profiles. This could range anywhere from 2 structures, up to 20 different replications! Is there something I'm missing here?
Not only the certificates management would be a problem, I don't know of any automatic way to proceed with the different steps of releasing an app (submitting from Xcode; creating a new version from iTunes Connect; configuring release notes, screenshots, etc); AFAIK the submit process is pretty manual and there's only so much that can be automatised.
So, how can I change this from having 20 manual releases to something that is more manageable?

Any solution or ideas would be greatly appreciated, even more if we can later integrate with Jenkins, acceptance tests and the whole nine yards ;D
Thanks in advance!

---

Alternatives received so far:
[Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools)
[Shenzhen](https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen)

Comment: Have you ever heard about https://fastlane.tools? You can automate some steps you cited with these tools.

Comment: Wow @GlaucoNeves! Seems like a really cool tool! Will check it out ASAP. Are you using it? Any insights? Thanks!

Comment: Your answer lies in what you said you don't want: you need to localize one app, not make 20.

Comment: Hahaha couldn't agree more @Slav. But this is a business requirement. Believe me I do not agree on this path, but is't not up to me. So, as we need N apps against my own judgement, how can I avoid to kill myself on each new release?